# How to get Aptana studio for older Eclipse versions

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I have an existing Eclipse library tool -- quite an old one -- running on Eclipse 3.4, and I would like to add in Aptana Studio. However, the current download specifies that it requires Eclipse 3.5 or better. A colleague of mine has Aptana running in his exactly the same version of the same tool -- presumably he got an older version that would work on the older Eclipse.

Can I download a version of Aptana to plug in to Eclipse 3.4?

Or, if not, can I grab the copy of Aptana from my colleague's machine and drop it into my own Eclipse?

Note that there are specific reasons why I need to use this older version of Eclipse, so replies along the lines of "upgrade your version of Eclipse to 3.5 or later!", while undoubtedly well-intentioned, won't be much use to me....

Edited on November 30: it is Eclipse *3.4* which I have, and I originally put 2.4 by mistake (which doesn't even exist!).

Comment: There was no Eclipse 2.4.  2.0->2.1->3.0 as shown at http://archive.eclipse.org/ .

Comment: Sorry -- my typo -- I have Eclipse *3.4* not 2.4. But the current download requires Eclipse 3.5 or better, and if I try and apply it to my eclipse 3.4 it says it is not compatible.

Comment: PS -- to be exact it is Eclipse 3.4.2 v20090122....

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the Studio's from your colleague's machine. The Studio is pretty much contained to the folder it's installed at (with some minor exception that should not stop you).

No packages are available for 2.x.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks -- so I can copy over his Aptana folder: then, how do I add it in to my Eclipse?

Comment: The Aptana folder holds the plugins, the features and more eclipse-elements. In case he installed a stand-alone version, you just copy all and run the executable that is there. In case he installed the Studio as a plugin, it's a bit more complicated. You can choose to copy all as well and work on the exact same eclipse setup as he does.